# How to refer a word to another section?

Tags: cross-referencing

Suppose I have a text like this

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,
sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore
magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam
```

I want to refer the word `euismod` to another section, so the reader can read about it in the right place.

What are the possibilities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use `cleveref` with `hyperref`. The bare `\ref` can also be used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks,linkcolor=magenta]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section{Simulation Techniques}\label{sec:sim}
Some text for this section here.
\newpage
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,
sed diam nonummy nibh euismod~(see section~\ref{sec:sim}) tincidunt ut laoreet dolore
magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam

% OR

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,
sed diam nonummy nibh euismod~(see~\cref{sec:sim}) tincidunt ut laoreet dolore
magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Without any additional package you can use `\label`,`\ref` and `\pageref` commands for cross referencing. (See wikibooks article on [cross-referencing](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing).)

To link the word directly, to the section you want, you can use `\hyperref` command from `hyperref` package. You will need to replace euismod by `\hyperref[sec:label]{euismod}`, where `sec:label` refers to the `label` for appropriate `section` and is set by adding `\label{sec:label}` somewhere in the section you want to link to. (Refer [hyperref manual](http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/ftp/doc/manual.html) or [wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks) more details on customization.)

The following example will link the word euismod to reference section.
The `blindtext` package is to just add random text to the document.

[image: linking words]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{ colorlinks = true, linkcolor = blue }
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy 
nibh \hyperref[sec:reference]{euismod} tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna 
aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam

\blinddocument
\section*{Reference section} \label{sec:reference}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```